# Is there any way to convert SQL Server 2008 mdf file to SQL Server Express version?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-server-ce

I have a mdf file which is SQL Server 2008 file. I want to convert it to SQL Server Express or SQL  Compact edition.

Is there any tool to convert it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For SQL Server - Express or Standard/Web/Developer - there is **no difference** in the file formats. Your MDF from your SQL Server 2008 will work on SQL Server 2008 (or 2008 R2) Express without any conversion or modification.

You can

- create a backup from SQL Server 2008 (into a `.bak` file) and restore it under SQL Server 2008 Express

or:

- you can detach the MDF file from your SQL Server 2008, copy the files to a new location (or new server), and then re-attach them to the SQL Server 2008 Express installed there.

The SQL Server Compact Edition is quite a different story, though - it's made up of a single `.SDF` file and cannot be easily created from an existing SQL Server 2008 MDF/LDF set of files.... I would be interested myself if there are any useful tools out there to migrate data from SQL Server 2008 (MDF/LDF) to a SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 (SDF) format...

**Update:** a quickie search found a few interesting candidates:

- [SQL Server to SQL Server Compact Edition Database Copy Utility (CodeProject)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlCompactCoptUtility.aspx)
- [Primeworks Data Port Wizard](http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DataPortWizard.html)

Comment: It should be noted that if the SQL Server version is newer than that Express Edition, it likely fails to attach the db file to the later, and some down-conversion is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you use features that do not work in Express Edition (such as partitioning), your 2008 database is also eligible in SQL Server 2008 Express. If the database is currently attached somewhere, you can check for these features using:

```
SELECT feature_name, feature_id
  FROM sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features;
```

Ideally this will return 0 rows. If it returns any rows, it is quite likely that you are using features not eligible in Express.

Also much safer to BACKUP/RESTORE than detach/attach if the database is in fact still attached to a 2008 instance - this way, if things go wrong, your original database is still intact. So if it is attached, you can run a BACKUP DATABASE command on the 2008 instance, then run a RESTORE DATABASE (probably using WITH MOVE options to store the files in the right location) on the Express instance. (Simpler still would be to set the database OFFLINE, copy the files, and set the database ONLINE again - but I still prefer the BACKUP/RESTORE route.)

**BACKUP:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865%28SQL.100%29.aspx

**RESTORE:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858%28SQL.100%29.aspx

If all you have is an MDF/LDF file, then on SQL Server 2008 Express you should be able to use CREATE DATABASE...FOR ATTACH / FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG. You can read about the syntax here:

**CREATE DATABASE:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061%28SQL.100%29.aspx

If you have issues with any of these commands, please post what you've tried and what error message you receive.

As for Compact Edition, no, I have no knowledge of any tools that will convert your database for you. The feature sets and even some of the language constructs are not compatible between the two.